# How to echo YEAR only from a php info containing including also day and month

Tags: php

I'm using PHP to send a complete date to another page (example 2021-02-23).
I'm calling this information 'year' but in the destination page I want it to display the year only (2021 in this case).

I am trying the following code, but it is actually printing me year a wrong '1970' for each value. How should I edit this in order to work correctly?

```
<?php $_GET['year']; echo date('Y', strtotime($date)); ?>
```

Comment: You haven't stored `$_GET['year']` to the variable `$date`. Should be `$date = $_GET['year'];`

Comment: thx it solved it

Comment: If you are getting "Jan 1 1970" .. that means you are effectively getting "0" out of the call(s) you are making. Also, that PHP code makes no sense... as a single $_GET['foo'] isn't any sort of operation. Looks like you need to set $date a bit better.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code to access the amount of the year

```
<?php
  $date = $_GET['year']; // 2021-02-23 OR any DateTime
  $year = explode('-', $date);
  echo $year[0];
?>
```

I hope helped you.

Comment: Dude, use `date() ` function

Comment: She or He wanted to retrieve the date data for a file but only the year did not need to receive the full date please read carefully, grateful.

Comment: Lol dude, OP code is the way to go. Not `explode` ‍♂️

Comment: Oh right but it's not the only way
although my answer didn't be useless anyway, thanks.